# How do you rotate the numbers in an numpy array of shape (n,) or (n,1)?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a numpy array:

```
>>> a 
array([0,1,2,3,4])
```

and I want to "rotate" it to get:

```
>>> b
array([4,0,1,2,3])
```

What is the best way?

I have been converting to a deque and back (see below) but is there a better way?

```
b = deque(a)
b.rotate(1)
b = np.array(b)
```

Comment: Just to be pedantic, `a.shape` is `(n,)` not `(n,1)`

Comment: @askewchan, I think that (n,) and (n,1) arrays [look the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635237/numpy-syntax-idiom-to-cast-n-array-to-a-n-1-array). Am I wrong?

Comment: You're right that they look the same, and even behave the same in many circumstances, including the `roll` function, but be careful in some cases where `ndim` might matter (for `a.shape` is `(n,)`, `a.ndim` is `1`; but for shape `(n,1)`, `a.ndim` is 2).  As you can see from the question you linked to, an axis must be added to get from the 1d to 2d case.

Comment: Fair point. In hindsight, to be consistent with the question title, I should have shown `a` with an (n,1) shape as `array([[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]])`. However, each of the answers does work for both (n,) and (n,1) shapes.

Comment: Yes, `roll` will be effectively be applied along the non-1 axis if there is only one, which is why my comment was nothing beyond pedantry :).  But if your array is `(n,m)` (or higher) it will roll along all the axes (the flattened array) which might give unexpected results.  The solution there is to just do `np.roll(a, axis=0)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use the [`numpy.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) function:

```
a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
b = np.roll(a,1)
print(b)
>>> [4 0 1 2 3]
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792465/how-to-do-circular-shift-in-numpy/15792525#15792525).

Answer (score 2):

```
numpy.concatenate([a[-1:], a[:-1]])
>>> array([4, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
b = a[-1:]+a[:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks. Note that I am using numpy arrays so you have to convert to list first... `b=list(a)[-1:]+list(a)[:-1]`

Comment: ... and I want a numpy array out so `b=np.array(list(a)[-1:]+list(a)[:-1])`